# using Silverlight 3's HtmlPage.Window.Navigate method to reuse an already open browser window

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser, silverlight-3.0, navigation

I want to use an external browser window to implement a preview functionality in a silverlight application.  There is a list of items and whenever the user clicks one of these items, it's opened in a separate browser window (the content is a pdf document, which is why it is handled ouside of the SL app).

Now, to achieve this, I simply use

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "_blank");
```

which works fine.

Now my client doesn't like the fact that every click opens up a new browser window.  He would like to see the browser window reused every time an item is clicked.  So I went out and tried implementing this:

**Option 1** - Use the overload of the Navigate method, like so:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "foo");
```

I was assuming that the window would be reused when the same target parameter value (foo) would be used in subsequent calls.
This does not work.  I get a new window every time.

**Option 2** - Use the PopupWindow method on the HtmlPage

```
HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "blah", new HtmlPopupWindowOptions());
```

This does not work.  I get a new window every time.

**Option 3** - Get a handle to the opened window and reuse that in subsequent calls

```
private HtmlWindow window;
private void navigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (window == null)
        window = HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "blah");
    else
        window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "blah");

    if (window == null)
        MessageBox.Show("it's null");
}
```

This does not work.  I tried the same for the PopupWindow() method and the window is null every time, so a new window is opened on every click.  I have checked both the EnableHtmlAccess and the IsPopupWindowAllowed properties, and they return true, [as they should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.popupwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx).

**Option 4** - Use Eval method to execute some custom javascript

```
private const string javascript = @"var popup = window.open('', 'blah') ; 
                                    if(popup.location != 'http://www.bing.com' ){
                                        popup.location = 'http://www.bing.com';
                                    }
                                    popup.focus();";

private void navigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Eval(javascript);
}
```

This does not work.  I get a new window every time.

**option 5** - Use CreateInstance to run some custom javascript on the page

```
private void navigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("thisIsPlainHell");
}
```

and in my aspx I have

```
function thisIsPlainHell() {
    var popup = window.open('http://www.bing.com', 'blah');
}
```

This doesn't work.  I get a new window every time.

Am I doing something wrong?  I'm definitely no javascript expert, so I'm hoping it's something obvious I'm missing here.

Cheers, 
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that the window.name property is lost when navigating to bing.com.  When I navigate to one of my custom pages it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is a security feature of the browser.  The re-use of named windows is limited to the domain of the document current being displayed by that window.

Your page hosting the Silverlight control will be running from "http://www.yoursite.com" hence it can only re-use window named "foo" if that window is also currently showing content from "http://www.yoursite.com".  Since your have loaded "http://www.bing.com" into that window it is no longer visible to code running in the context  "http://www.yoursite.com".  Hence when you open a window using "Foo" the browser doesn't see a current window with that name and hence creates another one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't a browser setting causing this? I use `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url))` and it always navigates the current tab that my silverlight control is sitting in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"), "_blank");
atm, which works fine, as I want to have it opening up in a new window.